# Put "edit" and/or "retag" links on the question list pages

Tags: feature-request, tags, edits

If I'm editing or retagging a question, I don't like to have to go into the question page itself. This is particularly cumbersome when doing librarian work - retagging multiple questions to conform to naming schemes.

Comment: You could create a Grease Monkey script that does this.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek IMO, the link you removed needs to remain visible as a minimal attempt at attribution. The actual licensing of the content appears murky, so what's legally required, or even if this content is legally permitted to have been copied to here, isn't clear to me without more research. However, at least for our referencing requirements, the link is required. The attribution should also have included the name of the original author.

Comment: Considering the minimal generic nature of the questions (I edited 3) and the general broken nature of even the archived posts - I'm not really sure there's any real thing to reference. It seems less noisy, and frankly it feels like a minor quibble over content that's orphaned for most part. Also figured I'd invoke the scream test to see if anyone minded

Answer (score 5):

I think this could be problematic.

In order to correctly re-tag a question, one needs to have a full understanding of exactly what's being asked and all of the context. For longer questions that don't fit 100% into the small letterbox visible on the main questions page, this could lead to a spate of bad (though well-intentioned) re-tagging.

I don't think it's too much to ask a user to click through to the full question in all it's glory, with all of the clarifying comments and gory detail, before allowing them to give it an edit.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed on this can we have a separate retag option (as you get before you can edit)

Comment: see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30268/could-we-make-it-easier-for-us-to-retag-questions-from-the-actual-question-page