# Could we make it easier for us to retag questions from the actual question page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, tags

When you have 2000 rep, to retag a question you have to click "edit", scroll down, change the tags field, and press save changes. It would be much easier if we just did retags asynchronous instead of by loading a new page. You hit retag, the list of the question's tags pops up on the same page, you edit, and press save (like how posting comments works). We would still have an edit button that takes you to a new page with full editing features for 2000 reppers (with the retag editing still there of course), but next to it a retag button for quick retagging of questions. Retag is probably the most common edit to a question, so streamlining it makes sense.

(I know I've seen this discusses elsewhere, but I can't find it. The other question said something about allowing you to edit a question's tags without even opening the question, but I think that's a different matter and would be better discussed in a separate question)

Comment: This question? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/put-edit-and-or-retag-links-on-the-question-list-pages

Comment: To the duplicate close voters: I'm usually aggro on dupes, but I think this is asking for something different than 1209, which in fact, OP mentions and describes why this is different.

Comment: That is about putting the links on the question list, this one is about putting a retag button next to the edit button.

Comment: moderators have this ability, fyi

Comment: i agree, that was something that surprised me after i reached 2k rep.

Comment: this is a dup of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30268, which for some reason was closed as a dup of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1209, even though 1209 is a different (albiet related) suggestion

Comment: @Kip 30268 is this question. :D

Comment: @CJD: this was merged. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you only want to retag, then just edit the tags and submit. No one's forcing you to change anything else.

Of course, if seeing the opportunity gives you a sudden urge to clean up the title and fix a few typos while you're in there, that's a Good Thing!

---

After thinking about this for a bit, it occurred to me that this might be useful in a limited set of circumstances. Specifically, those where you're trying to remove or merge tags that don't exist on enough questions to warrant a retag-request here on MSO.

So *if* that's your situation, [here's a Greasemonkey script that'll add a retag-only option](http://shog9.com/greasemonkey/scripts/so_quick_retag.user.js)...

[Obligatory screenshot http://shog9.com/greasemonkey/scripts/so_quick_retag.png](http://shog9.com/greasemonkey/scripts/so_quick_retag.png)

Comment: You win one (1) internet.  Prizes may be redeemed at your local ISP.  Taxes and delivery extra.  No substitutions or rainchecks.  Cannot be combined with other offers.

Comment: Yes but this marks the question as edited not just retaged - which is the main reason I have for getting a change

Comment: @Mark: I think you're getting too hung up on it; I still think there's *usually* a reason to edit more than just tags.

Answer (score 2):

I like this idea.  I had forgotten there was a separate UI just for tagging, and it would be nice to have the lighter-weight interface back.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it's not turned on for you - I thought it was a Moderators-only feature for testing for a little while, but we have an inline-retag ajax UI.

I don't see why it couldn't be used by anyone with enough rep.  (although honestly, I forget about it and tend to use the edit page)

Comment: I don't have 10,000 rep (yet :D), and I'm assuming you're talking about the 10000+ rep mods. So there is a feature in beta? that's good to know. :D

Comment: No, I'm a 10k rep person, and I don't have it.  Only super moderators have it.

Comment: SShhhh!!! They'll all want it! ;-p

Answer (score 1):

The feature [Tom Ritter explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30268/could-we-make-it-easier-for-us-to-retag-questions-from-the-actual-question-page/33051#33051) is now implemented as an additional benefit for 10k+ users.

Comment: Though I end up not using it half the time I could, just to leave a bit of explanation or a URL (e.g. to Meta) when retagging.