# Why isn't the "edit tags" link always visible?

Tags: discussion, edits, inline-tag-editor

I almost always forget that there's an "edit tags" link that enables quickly editing a question's tags without having to go into full edit mode. What contributes to my forgetting that it's there is that the link is invisible until you hover directly over where it exists.

Two questions:

1. Why not make the "edit tags" link visible at all times (keeping the same hover behavior)?
2. Why isn't the entire "post-menu" div (where a question's tags and "edit tags" links reside) set to trigger the visibiliity of this link?

[image]

Comment: Maybe change to feature request?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - nope, it's that way for your average question.

Comment: Ah I see, I thought you were saying that some questions don't show the link at all. Your complaint is that the link is relatively hidden. I'll confess, I sometimes click the Edit link even if I'm only fixing the tags (but usually I end up finding something else to fix too).

Comment: Really? The "retag" option is really visible to me. It has the same opacity and color as the "edit" option to the left of it.

Comment: @Yawus where is "retag"? I don't see it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Right under the tags, I have a list of options. It goes:

Comment: link | edit | retag | flag

Comment: @Yawus on every question I look at, it's `link | edit | close | flag` - I suppose this difference has to do with rep.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Maybe there's a bug where the "close" option just shows over the "retag" option once you get close privileges. I'm totally willing receive a lot of upvotes so I can try to reproduce this *hint hint wink wink*

Comment: Well maybe the feature request is "continue showing the `retag` option even for users who have gained the privilege to close questions." In most cases, the div holding the tags is wider than the div holding the links under it, so it's not like showing an extra link there is going to be a huge visual wart.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30268/could-we-make-it-easier-for-us-to-retag-questions-from-the-actual-question-page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be: **you have too much rep** to see the static `retag` link.

For lower-rep users, `retag` is a link under the tag div, as @Yawus pointed out. When you gain the privilege to vote to close (VtC), that link is replaced with `close`. I presume it does the same thing as edit tags, but lacking a low-rep sock puppet to try it out with, that's the best I can do.

In any case, as I stated in a comment, maybe the feature request should be:

> Continue showing the retag option even for users who have gained the privilege to vote to close questions.

In most cases, the div holding the tags is wider than the div holding the links under it, so it's not like showing an extra link there is going to be a huge visual wart. And this would make the "now you see me, now you don't" `edit tags` button redundant (again, presuming it works in the same way). I'm sure there is a reason it was designed this way, but I think discoverability trumps the only reason I can think of right now (aesthetics).

Comment: I guess this is a case of " Mo' Internet monies, mo' problems".

Comment: Hmmm? This question is specifically referring only to the "edit tags" link that appears next to the tags for 10k+ users. By default, it's hidden and only shows up when you hover over the tags division. He wants it to just *always* be shown, no matter what.

Comment: @animuson and I'm suggesting an alternative, that even 10k+ users have a permanent retag link under the div. The div is hidden because it's not a tag, which I've gathered from other comments, but this makes it less discoverable.

Comment: The problem is they're different functionalities. The "retag" link actually loads an additional page to retag the question. The "edit tags" link loads the editing box inline with the question for faster retgging. See [What is the reason for removing the retag link for users with full editing rights?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88151) and [Why is inline tag editing not available with retag privileges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117624)

Comment: So if they're different functionality, why not just add `edit tags` to the lower set of links for 10k users, instead of making it a whack-a-mole hidden div?

Answer (score 1):

Because "edit tags" isn't a tag and only when you're looking to interact with tags (ie, your mouse is over that area) should it be presumed that you might want to edit them, which is precisely when the link appears.

It's a bit hidden, yes, but it would be a visual wart if it was always visible.  It's the same reason comment controls don't appear until you hover over them as well.

Comment: Well I wonder if it shouldn't be a link underneath, `edit | edit tags | close`

Comment: In my mind it'd be a bit redundant/busy since "edit" allows you to edit tags as well.  It's more of a convenience than a necessity.  Plus, what would happen if you clicked your proposed "edit tags" link?  Would it do what the current one does?  Because that would be interacting with a separate (albeit spatially close) section of the page, which doesn't sit right.

Comment: Obviously "edit tags" isn't a tag, and it's trivial to set it apart visually. My question really involves why it's so hidden. It would be more useful if it was shown all the time or the visibility was triggered by the div it resides in.