# Add 'edit tags' ability on the main 'Questions' page

Tags: feature-request, tags, edits, questions-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Put "edit" and/or "retag" links on the question list pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/put-edit-and-or-retag-links-on-the-question-list-pages)

I was wondering if we could add the 'edit tags' button (below)

[image: edit tag]

to the list of 'Questions' page (something like this)

[image: questions]

Comment: Nice request. Would be usefull

Comment: You forget to mention how much context you lose when you only read the first line of a question

Comment: @random - Thx for the downvote.  In my example, I would not need to read the whole question as it obvious its related to AES.  I agree some questions might need further investigation by reading the question.