# Can we add review question option to question list?

Tags: feature-request, edits, review

I love the fact that when [reviewing first questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) we have the ability to use the 'Review Question' link to see if it needs any edits, comments or to up/down-vote it without actually having to open the question.

Can we add this option to the question list?  Then when we are editing/retagging questions we don't have to go into the question to see the full post.

This is a similar request to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/put-edit-and-or-retag-links-on-the-question-list-pages) which I think is still a great suggestion but this is different because I am requesting the Review Question link to be added to the questions.

<sub>* I would add a screenshot of what I am referring to but the airplane wifi is failing when I try to add an image.</sub>